# VBA to Use Inputs to

Tags: excel, vba, structure, code-organization

So I'm new to VBA and it has been a long time since I had to program something like this. I'm trying to use six different inputs to format cells. Right now, if I could just get the inputs in x, y, z to format the corresponding cell, that would be great! I'm trying to avoid writing over 125 different if statements or cases and need a way to copy whatever color is in the B column to the appropriate x, y, z box. How can I do this iteratively?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUdA0.jpg)

Edit: Basically what I'm trying to do is locate a cell that corresponds to an x, y, z input. Right now, the l, w, h don't matter. I'm just trying to go through all the cells in the z-planes and to find the one that matches the three input conditions (x,y,z).

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53160113/edit) and show us the code you already have. Also explaining what  "the appropriate x. y. z box" actually is would be helpful. You may also want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How does cell `3,2,1` correspond to `Sub_3`?  I thought maybe they were coordinates, but in the first box it's in column `3` & `4`, rows `2` & `3` which doesn't seem to correspond to the `2,2` in `Sub_3`.  Where does the z-plane come into it seeing as in a cell you can't move stuff forward & backwards?  `l,w,h` - width of a column, height of a row, length of a something?

Answer (score 0):

Unfinished but, this should get you started in the right direction.

This will add your 3d object to an array.
 AddValue will insert a value in the array at the appropriate locations
 PostArray will display the array at a given location.
 Note: There is no error checking in either function.

Your example Height (named depth in mine) is incorrect for sub_3.  If height 0 shows on a single depth, then 3 should show on 4 depths (the starting depth extended 3 depth layers).  Much like length and width values of 1 extend one past the original position.

[image]

```
Sub Test()

    Dim oArr(1 To 5, 1 To 5, 1 To 5) As String

    Call AddValue(oArr, 4, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0, "s1")
    Call AddValue(oArr, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, "s2")
    Call AddValue(oArr, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, "s3")

    Call PostArray(oArr, Sheet1.Range("I4"))
End Sub

Private Sub AddValue(ByRef Arr() As String, ByVal iX As Integer, ByVal iY As Integer, ByVal iZ As Integer, _
                        ByVal iLength As Integer, ByVal iWidth As Integer, iDepth As Integer, _
                        ByVal Value As String)

    Dim oLength As Integer
    Dim oWidth As Integer
    Dim oDepth As Integer

    For oLength = iX To iX + iLength
        For oWidth = iY To iY + iWidth
            For oDepth = iZ To iZ + iDepth
                Arr(oLength, oWidth, oDepth) = Value
            Next
        Next
    Next

End Sub


Private Sub PostArray(ByRef Arr() As String, ByVal PostRange As Range)

    Dim oX As Integer
    Dim oY As Integer
    Dim oZ As Integer

    For oX = 1 To 5
        For oY = 1 To 5
            For oZ = 1 To 5
                PostRange.Offset(oX - 1, (oY - 1) + ((oZ - 1) * 6)).Value = Arr(oX, oY, oZ)
            Next
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Additional work

- PostArray values from are going left to right, rather than your example of Right to left.  If you read from right to left in your grids why arn't the depths also listed in the same direction? If you need it in that order, you'll likely want to separate the math to get the cooridinate of the 1,1 position for each depth, and a separate calculation for the offsets within that grid.
- PostArray listed values instead of color, but if you enter the color as your value for each position you could set the color instead of posting the value.
- Will need a loop to call AddValue using values from your worksheet rather than manually entering them into an array.

Comment: Wow thanks! I ended up assigning values to the cells and then hiding those values in the formatting and performing a simple search and fill based on input values.